# How to access property in core plot

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-plot

HI how i can access property xScaleType of CPTXYGraph in core plot for iPhone application.

i m accessing something like this but unable to get

```
CPTScaleType* obj = graph.xScaleType
```

Answer (score 1):

The scale type is a property of the plot space.

```
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = graph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.xScaleType = CPTScaleTypeLog; // default is CPTScaleTypeLinear
```